# Glob markdown files on github action only returns `docs` folder

Tags: github, github-actions

I have multiple folders in my project containing markdown files. I want to run `cspell` (and other tools) against them. Unfortunately, only the markdown files in the `docs` subfolder are returned in the blob.

Here's a snippet of an actions file:

```yaml
      - name: 'Spellchecking Content'
        run: |
          npm install cspell -g
          pwd
          ls ./**/*.md
          npx cspell $(ls ./**/*.md) -c ${{ github.workspace }}/cspell.json
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}
```

Again, the problem is that the `ls ./**/*.md` in GitHub actions **only returns the markdown files in the `docs` folder** and no markdown files in the other subfolders.

**Troubleshooting:**

- `pwd` prints the correct, home folder of the project workspace
- `ls ./**/*.md` only lists the files in the `docs` subfolder
- I've attempted to set the `working-directory` explicitly
- The command works on my local machine, just not on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

So, interestingly enough, if I replace

```
npx cspell $(ls ./**/*.md) -c ${{ github.workspace }}/cspell.json
```

with

```
npx cspell $(find . -name '*.md') -c ${{ github.workspace }}/cspell.json
```

it works.

Is this a bug or documented limitation in GitHub actions?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles here...

From an answer to my same post on GitHub actions discussion, I need to enable the `globstar` options.

Resulting snippet:

```yaml
      - name: 'Spellchecking Content'
        run: |
          shopt -s globstar
          npm install cspell -g
          npx cspell $(ls ./**/*.md) -c ${{ github.workspace }}/cspell.json
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}
```